# Is it a good idea to leave helper :all in the applications_controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view-helpers

I am working for a company where I inherited their administration site.  The guy before me didn't use view helpers much so 95% of the code in these helpers is mine.

I just got bit by a problem where he had the helper :all line in his application_controller, which means all helpers are available to all views.  I got bit because I created the same named method in two different helpers and of course it took the last one instead of the correct one.  It drove me nuts wondering how a view helper that had NOTHING to do with the controller I was in was being loaded and the wrong method being selected.

My question is, is this a good idea to leave in your application controller?  I would think that the standard would be to ONLY include the view helper for THAT particular view's controller.  So if I have foo controller and foo views, only the foo_helper should be included.  Not foo2_helper and foo3_helper.  (I know if I were to need foo2_helper or foo3_helper you can put "helper foo2" or "helper foo3" in the controller, but that would be by choice,  not automatic.)

I can't seem to find an answer to if this is a good idea or not.  I found one site that said this is the default, really??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

IMO helpers in the `ApplicationController` are specifically *meant* to be shared across the application (which I guess is kind of obvious when I say it out loud).

Helpers used *only* in a single controller's views belong in that single controller.

If there are non-global helpers in the application controller they're likely in the wrong spot.

Comment: I think I might have worded my question wrong.  I meant the helper files in the app/helpers.  For instance, I can have a foo_controller and a foo2_controller.  That would then mean I have a foo_helper and a foo2_helper.  When I'm working in the foo_controller, I really do not want to load foo2_helper.  If I loaded foo2_helper with foo_controller, that would mean 2 methods of the same name in both foo_helper and foo2_helper would conflict.  I do agree with your point about ApplicationController.  Every method in there *should* be available to all controllers.  Thanks

Comment: Ah. Well, IIRC it was part of the Rails 2 templates; maybe people just got used to it. Use clear_helpers to turn off that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I keep `helper :all` in my ApplicationController, because I order my helpers depending of what  I use them to, not depending of the controller.

That way, you can reuse the same helper in two different controllers.

Comment: But wouldn't the application_helper be used for the purpose you describe?  There are some methods I would like to span all views.  Those methods I put in the application_helper.  But if I have a method that *should only* be available to a certain controller and it's views, I put it in it's respective place like I described in my question.

Comment: That's a very good way to end up having a very big, and unreadable ApplicationHelper.

Comment: unless you use `helper 'my_own_custom_global_helpers/a_specific_helper'` to organise this a bit. see http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper

Comment: @Damien  I do see your point.  So far though we've tried to keep the "global" helper methods to a minimum and it's a pretty large application.  I try to keep methods the methods pretty tight to their controllers/views.  Guess it's just a difference in "ways of doing things".  As I think about your idea more, it definitely has it's merits.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's called DRY.
It doesn't mean you should place all your code in `application_helper.rb` and use it in every place of your rails project, but it can help sometimes.